# Gulp watch not putting files in the right directory

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

Here is my gulp watch task, the only issue is that the transpiled files are ending up directly in `build/` as opposed to in `build/original/path/` - how can I preserve the path structure when the files are transpiled to the `build/` dir?

```
gulp.task('transpile-watch-js', function () {
  return gulp.watch('lib/**/*.js', function (obj) {
      if (obj.type === 'changed') {
        gulp.src(obj.path)
          .pipe(babel())
          .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `gulp.src` with the base option.

#### Examples, considering your sourcefiles path matches the pattern `'folder1/folder2/folder3/*.js'`

If you write:

1. `gulp.src(obj.path, {base: '.'})`

   `gulp.dest('build')` will write in `build/folder1/folder2/folder3/`
2. `gulp.src(obj.path, {base: './folder1'})`

   `gulp.dest('build')` will write in `build/folder2/folder3/`
3. `gulp.src(obj.path, {base: './folder1/folder2'})`

   `gulp.dest('build')` will write in `build/folder3/`

And so on.

Comment: In this case is was necessary to - `gulp.src(obj.path, {base: './lib'})` - but yeah that's the idea!

Comment: Yup I used a generic folder structure in the answer. Added examples in the answer in case it is useful for others